# Sorting an array in JavaScript using a reference array and swap function

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I seem to have come across what's basically a leetcode question in some actual practical code I'm writing. My problem is that I need to sort an array using a reference array of indices and a swap function.

It may help to know the context of this problem. It's a simplified, isolated version of what I'm facing when trying to come up with a script to sort layers by object position within Adobe Illustrator via ExtendScript. That's why swapping is necessary, and that's why there's a reference array as opposed to just using the `.sort()` function.

The `arrayToBeSorted` contains the actual data that I'm trying to sort. The `referenceArray` is an already-sorted list of the indices of `arrayToBeSorted`. This `referenceArray` describes what order the items in the `arrayToBeSorted` should end up in, by referring the indices of the items in `arrayToBeSorted`.

**Setup Example 1:**

```
// index              0      1       2       3       4      5                   
arrayToBeSorted = [ "six", "four", "one", "three", "two", "five" ]
referenceArray  = [   2,     4,      3,      1,      5,     0    ]

function swapItems(a, b) {
    var temp = arrayToBeSorted[a];
    arrayToBeSorted[a] = arrayToBeSorted[b];
    arrayToBeSorted[b] = temp;
}

// desired outcome:
algorithmToSortArray(arrayToBeSorted, referenceArray)
// should return this: 
[
    "one",   // was arrayToBeSorted[2]
    "two",   // was arrayToBeSorted[4]
    "three", // was arrayToBeSorted[3]
    "four",  // was arrayToBeSorted[1]
    "five",  // was arrayToBeSorted[5]
    "six"    // was arrayToBeSorted[0]
]
```

**Setup Example 2:**

```
// index              0       1       2       3        4         5                   
arrayToBeSorted = [ "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "purple", "orange" ]
referenceArray  = [   5,      1,      4,      2,       0,        3     ]

function swapItems(a, b) {
    var temp = arrayToBeSorted[a];
    arrayToBeSorted[a] = arrayToBeSorted[b];
    arrayToBeSorted[b] = temp;
}

// desired outcome:
algorithmToSortArray(arrayToBeSorted, referenceArray)
// should return this: 
[
    "orange",  // was arrayToBeSorted[5]
    "green",   // was arrayToBeSorted[1]
    "purple",  // was arrayToBeSorted[4]
    "blue",    // was arrayToBeSorted[2]
    "red",     // was arrayToBeSorted[0]
    "pink"     // was arrayToBeSorted[3]
]
```

**Solution constraints:**

The solution should **exclusively use the swap function to move items around in** `arrayToBeSorted` **in-place**, and should preferably be optimized for the least number of swaps possible.

***What would be the best way to write `algorithmToSortArray()`?***

Comment: It's "indices", and why are you not using `.sort()`?

Comment: Edited for spelling. I'm not using ```.sort()``` because this problem is an abstraction for sorting layers via scripting within an Adobe program, where .sort() wouldn't work.

Comment: Why do you necessarily need to swap?

Comment: Swapping is necessary because in the actual application of the solution, there would be other items between items in the array that would not be part of the sorting process, and would be ignored. However, those ignored items have to retain their place in the overall order. Not sure if that's clear... Essentially, this necessity for swapping is a result of this code working within Adobe Illustrator. It's a frustrating constraint.

Comment: Are you looking for something as simple as `const result = referenceArray .map (i => arrayToBeSorted [i])`?  This does not swap in place, but maps; however it is quite simpler.

Comment: I need to swap in-place because the items in the array represent layers within Adobe Illustrator. ```.map()``` wouldn't work in this case as it creates a new array.

Answer (score 2):

This version is fairly simple:

```js
const swap = (xs, i, j) => 
  [xs [j], xs [i]] = [xs [i], xs [j]]

const refSort = (vals, refs) => {
  const indices = Array .from (vals, (_, i) => i)
  refs .forEach ((r, i) => {
    const j = indices .indexOf (r)
    swap (indices, i, j)
    swap (vals, i, j)
  })
  return vals
}

console .log (
  refSort (["six", "four", "one", "three", "two", "five"], [2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 0])
)
console .log (
  refSort (["red", "green", "blue", "pink", "purple", "orange"], [5, 1, 4, 2, 0, 3])
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We simultaneously re-sort the indices `[0, 1, 2, ..., length]` and our values by placing each of our references in place using `swap`s on both, based on the reference indices.  There are `n` swaps, and if they are over-expensive, we can remove useless swaps with

```js
  refs .forEach ((r, i) => {
    const j = indices .indexOf (r)
    if (i !== j) {
      swap (indices, i, j)
      swap (vals, i, j)
    }
  })
```

I think this would have to be minimal, although we do double-swaps everywhere.

This does no error-checking.  If `refs.length` is different from `vals.length`, this would likely fail.

It's not clear to me if this simple approach will expand out to your real problem, but if not, it might serve as a basis for that.  In that case, you might open a new question with a more real-world example.  (Perhaps some changed values interspersed with others left alone, although I guess the fixed points above -- such as 'green' -- might be enough to demonstrate that it should work.  It's just not clear to me.)

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with another solution that only use the `swapItems` method to update the `arrayToBeSorted`. I'm pretty sure it could be done simpler by storing individually the changement of position of each number instead of the swap per "loop" but it's getting late and this one work so i hope this helps you enough.

```
function algorithmToSortArray(arrayToBeSorted, referenceArray) {
    const changeHistory = []
    for(let i = 0; i < referenceArray.length; i++) {
        number = referenceArray[i]

        for(let j = 0; j < changeHistory.length; j++) {
            if(changeHistory[j][0] === number) {
                number = changeHistory[j][1]
            } else if (changeHistory[j][1] === number) {
                number = changeHistory[j][0]
            }
        }

        if (i !== number) {  // this avoid some unnecessary swaps
            swapItems(i, number)
        }
        changeHistory[i] = [i, number]
    }

    return arrayToBeSorted
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because it doesn't use the swap function on ```arrayToBeSorted```. The initial array must be modified in-place using the swap function.

Comment: Hey @boguslavsky i've updated my answer with another solution, this should match what you need, hope this helps